# ASP.NET Identity token missed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, token, asp.net-identity

I use [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity) in my project, it worked well, but suddenly I found that all of my user's tokens are missing without any reset and all of my authorized methods are not working anymore. I don't know what happened.

Comment: what is the mode in which you are authenticating, is it custom login or are you using social logins. Hope you are using Owin Middlewares

Comment: I used  social logins and it is Owin Middlewares

Comment: enable the tracing for the owin middlewares in the web.config file and the traces should give you a good hint on whats going on

Comment: also check if you are getting an `error=access_denied` in the callback url query string from the external idp